# Pass Data Like State When Authenticating Twitter Account using Express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

I wonder if Twitter authentication can pass state-like what [Facebook has](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). But when I search along the documentation, there's no clue about it.

So here's my case.

When user hit the endpoint when it will redirect to Twitter authorization page, there's data I need to pass, let's call it "name" so the endpoint would look like **http://localhost/auth/twitter?name=abcd** then the endpoint will redirect user to Twitter authorization page, user will authorize their account, and Twitter will take user to registered callback URL. And the callback URL will append the name's data before so it will looks like **http://localhost/auth/twitter/callback?name=abcd**.

Is it possible to do this in Express.js without session?

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to Facebook, when you get the request token using a callback URL, append the state to it and the state will be redirected to callback from Twitter. There is no need for a session.